# How to load all classes of a namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

I hate PHP namespaces. They don't work as normal ones, or at least as I expect. Anyway, since I'm trying to write a small library, I have to deal with them, and I was wondering if you can manage to treat them as you would for C# or Java, maybe using `spl_autoload_*` functions. Something like:

Library:

```
<?php
namespace A
{
    class MyAClass {...}
}

namespace A\B
{
    class MyBClass {...}
}
?>
```

and the app:

```
<?php
include("library\autoloader.php");

use A; //Loads every class in A namespace
use A\B; //Loads every class in A\B namespace

$obj = new MyAclass();
$obj2 = new MyBCLass();
?>
```

I tried simply:

```
<?php
function autoload($name)
{
    //echo "loading {$name}.php<br />";
    require_once($name.".php");
}
spl_autoload_register("autoload");
?>
```

but I'm forced to do this:

```
<?php
include("Library\autoload.php");

$obj = new MyNamespace\MyClass();
?>
```

I'd like to do something like this indeed:

```
<?php
include("Library\autoload.php");

use MyNamespace;    

$obj = new MyClass();
?>
```

Comment: What was the problem with the one that "you tried simply"? What is wrong with the one you were "forced to do"? In the last snippet, just put `use \MyNamespace\MyClass;` and then it will work.

Comment: For the sake of balance: I ♥ PHP namespaces!

Comment: Incidentally, your first snippet is syntactically correct, but I don't advise using braces with namespaces - the guidelines in PHP are one class per file, and so `namespace MyNamespace;` is sufficient. You _can_ break this guideline, but I don't think there is any good reason to.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, but if I have 100 class in MyNamespace I want to be able to access all of them just by their name, neither writing a use for every one of them nor writing MyNamespace\MyClass.

Comment: Do you know the using keyword in C#? Or the import one in Java. I wanted to achieve kinda the same thing

Comment: @Phate01 yes, you'll need to either do `use MyNamespace\MyClass` for all of them, or do `new MyNamespace\MyClass()` for all of them. Get used to it. However, you should not be using 100 classes in the same file, that is a definite code smell.

Comment: @Phate01 `using` does not exist for PHP, unfortunately. And there is no way to duplicate this.

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want with PHP on its own (and personally I don't find using the PHP approach a bother). However if you are finding the number of classes you have is getting unwieldy, maybe you need an object factory? You can then refer to classes however you like.

Comment: Protip: it doesn't help to lead a question with that sentence. It also doesn't help to get irate over an issue you have no control over. PHP namespaces aren't Python modules or whatever. Get used to it or abandon PHP.

Comment: OP: the question is a good one, but please keep your responses professional here. I've rolled back the last edit - sorry! I hope you find the responses you are looking for. (The assumption that you are putting several classes in one file is not surprising, given your first piece of code - two classes and two namespaces).

Comment: I apologize, I assumed that people get that as an example only

Comment: You can always edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 8):

1. No you cannot load all classes in a namespace. A namespace is literally just an addition to the class/function naming system, it has no intrinsic connection to files or such. Since classes are "loaded" by including their file, and since namespaces are not linked to files, there could be any number of files in any number of places in your filesystem which contain classes of a namespace. There's no way for PHP to locate those automagically.
2. You *can* simply load all files in a folder by looping over a `glob` result and `include`. If you organise your files according to namespaces, that'll "load all classes in a namespace."
3. You shouldn't really do this and instead use autoloaders, which include files as needed when needed. That requires you to write a correct autoloader, its unclear what the issue is with yours. In order to use autoloaders effectively you should use one file per class named after the class. Your autoloader will also need to construct the correct relative path.
4. `use` does not load a class. `use` only aliases a namespaced name into a shorter or alternative name within the current file. The class is only loaded the first time it's required; e.g. when you write `new Foo` or `extends Foo`.

If you want to be able to write something like `use Foo\*` and then refer to all classes within `Foo` by their bare name: that's not possible in PHP. The best you can do is to shorten the namespace prefix, e.g. `use Foo\Bar as B`, then use `B\Baz` everywhere.

Comment: *You shouldn't really do this and instead use autoloaders* I don't get this as I said in my question that I would use autoloaders, and I put an `include("Library\autoload.php");` in almost all my examples

Comment: I've not needed to use them, but I wonder if a service locator might help the OP? Classes are registered with some sort of service, and can be given any sort of short identifier as required. And, bonus, they are built automatically by a factory anyway.

Comment: @Phate01 Yes you did, but you're also leading the question with "load all classes...". So I'm clarifying both points.

Answer (score 3):

To extend from the comment by @halfer, your last codeblock is invalid PHP.

To illustate what you *can* do (as mentioned by @halfer again, you should use 1 class per file):

```
namespace Vendor\Package;
class AClass{}
```

To initialize this you can either do:

```
$a = new Vendor\Package\AClass();
```

or

```
use Vendor;
$a = new Vendor\Package\AClass();
```

or

```
use Vendor\Package;
$a = new Package\AClass();
```

or

```
use Vendor\Package\AClass;
$a = new AClass();
```

or

```
use Vendor\Package\AClass as B;
$a = new B();
```

or

```
use Vendor\Package as C;
$a = new C\AClass;
```

I hope you get the gist of it :)

Also, to fully utilize the power of namespacing, you should organize your files into folders according to their namespace and use an autoloader, e.g. the example above should give you the following folder structure:

```
Vendor
  Package
    AClass.php
```

Look into http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ for a generally accepted convention for Autoloading

Comment: Is there a way to load the class only by its name, without writing use `Vendor\Package\AClass;`?

Comment: @Phate01 you're really fixated on this, aren't you? You've asked the same question 5 times differently, and we have given you the same answer: no.

Comment: As you explained me the rules I have already read a hundred times, I assumed that you didn't get my question properly. My mistake

Comment: Thanks Mister @Populus